# Can I extract schema information from empty Access tables with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-access

I'm trying to extract the schema from Microsoft Access databases as part of a larger project to merge ~300 databases. Using my current code, I can only get table names, not field names.

I've been using this win32com code snippet, but I'm open to other suggestions (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/528868-extraction-and-manipulation-class-for-microsoft-ac/?in=user-4074475)

```
db = AccessDb('''c:\x.mdb''')
tbls = db.getTables()
for tbl in tbls:
    fields = tbl.getFields()
    for field in fields:
        print '%s - %s' %(tbl,field)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `print '%s - %s' %(tbl.Name, field.Name)`?

Comment: @marlan - thats what i was expecting, but tbl.getFields() was not returning anything - likely through my ignorance of how to apply it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `cursor.tables()` and `cursor.columns()` methods in pyodbc will reveal the information you seek, even for empty tables. For example

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
connStr = (
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"DBQ=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Test.accdb;"
    )
conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
crsr = conn.cursor()
table_list = [x[2] for x in crsr.tables() if x[3]=='TABLE']
for table_name in table_list:
    column_list = [x[3] for x in crsr.columns(table_name)]
    for column_name in column_list:
        print('[{0}].[{1}]'.format(table_name, column_name))
crsr.close()
conn.close()
```

See the pyodbc [cursor](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) documentation for more details.